# Operation timeout with SSH connection

Tags: go, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote EC2-server through Go code using a PEM key provided by AWS. I am able to log in to the server through the command line using the PEM key.

I have done the following so far.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func publicKey(path string) ssh.AuthMethod {
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return ssh.PublicKeys(signer)
}

func runCommand(cmd string, conn *ssh.Client) {
    sess, err := conn.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer sess.Close()
    sessStdOut, err := sess.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, sessStdOut)
    sessStderr, err := sess.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go io.Copy(os.Stderr, sessStderr)
    err = sess.Run(cmd) // eg., /usr/bin/whoami
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "ec2-user",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            publicKey("mykey"),
        },
        Timeout:         15 * time.Second,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "remote-server:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    runCommand("whoami", conn)
}
```

I keep getting the following error. What am I missing?

```
panic: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp "localhost"->"remotehost:22": read: operation timed out
```

In the above message I have replaced the IP addresses of the actual machines with bogus names.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this since I was using an incorrect port to connect to :). I should be using port 22 for SSH, but was using some other service port.

Thanks.